# how to insert a ribbon inside a div how background without images only pure css?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background ribbon inside a div without images with only pure CSS.

I tried using `:after` and `:before` but didn't have any luck.

The ribbon is green, and must be same as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJsj9.png

[image: Ribbon screenshot]

Anyone here that can help me? Remember - my div can grow in height with the content.

Comment: We will gladly help if you show what you have so far, in terms of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I applied some transforms on the `:after` pseudo-element. [**Here's how**](http://jsfiddle.net/LFaJb/14/):

[image: Screenshot]

```
.ribbon {
    background: #04F;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ribbon:after {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    background: #0F4;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    top: 0;
    right: -70%;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
            transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
}
```

Just work with the padding, text-align and colors to achieve the exact effect.

Comment: don't forget the important requirement of the OP: ***my div can grow in height with the content*** In fact this requirement is still unclear on the exact effect he wants.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, there was some error if the height exceeded the width. I think it's fixed. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFaJb/12/).

Comment: And if the height _grows with the content_, `height: 100%` is needed on the `.ribbon`. [See update](http://jsfiddle.net/LFaJb/14/).

Comment: wow, very thanks, it works nice in jsfiddle, i will apply it on my project.